# Executable C # and Visual Studio 2012 and ILMerge

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, executable, ilmerge

I have a program in C # that I created, which uses 3 dll file: 
Ionic.Zip.dll, System.Browser.dll and System.Json 0.1.1.dll

to create a single executable I used ILMerge and the following error appeared?

"There Was a problem Trying to merge. aseembly the output might not work as expeced. 
unresolved assembly reference notes allowed: 
Community.CsharpSqlite.SQLiteClient. "

I also used smartassembly and the same error persists!

then I'm lost! I just want to have a single executable to my solution without reported Dll file!

thank you for your help :)

Comment: Looks like your program uses `Community.CsharpSqlite.SQLiteClient` as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is that one of the 3 dll I  merges   needs the SQLite library. 
I downloaded this project [csharpsqlite](https://csharp-sqlite.googlecode.com/files/csharp-sqlite_3_7_7_1_71.zip)  and generated two files. DLL missing : Community.CsharpSqlite.dll and Community.CsharpSqlite.SQLiteClient.dll and then add other dll files 
And finally create my executable with ILMerge and the problem is solved :)

Thank you again :)